# Передача элементов массива в функцию как отдельных аргументов. C#

Tags: c#

Как передать элементы массива в функцию в качестве отдельных аргументов?

Можно сделать так:

```cs
f(arr[0], arr[1], arr[2])
```

Но это не всегда удобно.

На `Python` можно было делать так:

```py
f(*arr)
```

как делать на `C#` почему-то не могу найти.

Comment: Ключевое слово `params`

Comment: @Kalmankantaja ```params``` позволяют собрать несколько аргументов функции в массив. Мне же нужно наоборот массив передать как несколько аргументов. Например передать массив из 2х элементов в ```Random.Next()```

Comment: В C# такой возможности нет. / Попытки прикрутить Deconstruct или List Pattern код не сократят.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Мне же нужно наоборот массив передать как несколько аргументов. Например передать массив из 2х элементов в `Random.Next()`

Как в питоне конечго же не получится, но способ можно написать самому

```
private readonly Random rnd = Random.Shared;

public int RandomRange(int[] array, int offset = 0)
{
    return rnd.Next(array[offset], array[offset + 1]);
}
```

```
int[] array = new[] { 0, 10, 20, 45 };
int number = RandomRange(array, 1); // [10..20)
```

Или так

```
public int RandomRange(int[] array)
{
    return rnd.Next(array[0], array[1]);
}
```

```
int number = RandomRange(array[1..2]); // [10..20)
```

Первый способ оптимальнее, второй спавнит новый массив из 2 элементов, поэтому если надо очень много генерировать, то лучше первый.

Есть вариант еще со спанами, выглядит как второй, работает как первый, но я его для сохранения простоты ответа оставлю за рамками. Про вариант с небезопасным кодом вообще промолчу, он кстати похож на питоновский был бы.

Comment: Жаль что нельзя( Но спасибо за ответ!

Comment: @rew зато много всего другого можно